# The page that displays Posts on homepage

Tags: posts, pages, query, sql, blog

I want to know the page responsible for displaying the blog posts in WordPress. Where I can probably expect to find the SQL query and post rendering so I can edit some stuff by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are thinking wordpress is, is not like that. You can't find the query and alter it like you do in plain PHP. There are filters and actions and a whole architecture to play with pages and posts. I suggest you to read wordpress documentation and Codex.

If you are a programmer then have understanding with PHP and little bit of database then you will be amazed to see the architecture of wordpress.

Suggested Reading:

[Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/)

[How Wordpress Theme Works - by Mashable](http://mashable.com/2011/01/10/how-wordpress-themes-actually-work-infographic/)